# Spark join on multiple keys extremely slow

Tags: apache-spark, inner-join, outer-join

I have implemented inner join using Spark's Java API. Out of two datasets, one is expected to have high volumes of data around 1,000,000 rows and other would have around 5000 rows.

```
DS1
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5    |
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| S1 |  1 |  2 |  6 | 3     |
| S2 |  1 |  3 |  7 | 2     |
| S3 |  1 |  4 |  8 | 11    |
| S4 |  1 |  5 |  9 | null  |
+----+----+----+----+-------+

DS2
+----+-----+
| EK | EV  |
+----+-----+
| C1 |  S2 |
| C4 |  7  |
| C3 |  2  |
| C5 |  2  |
+----+-----+

Expected output
+----+----+----+----+-------+----+----+
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5    | EK | EK |
+----+----+----+----+-------+----+----+
| S1 |  1 |  2 |  6 | 3     | C3 | 2  |
| S2 |  1 |  3 |  7 | 2     | C1 | S2 |
| S2 |  1 |  3 |  7 | 2     | C4 | 7  |
| S2 |  1 |  3 |  7 | 2     | C5 | 2  |
| S3 |  1 |  4 |  8 | 11    |null|null|
| S4 |  1 |  5 |  9 | null  |null|null|
+----+----+----+----+-------+----+----+
```

I have tried left join, but that was too slow. We then tried an alternate implementation with inner join, but even inner join is very slow.

Left join

```
Dataset<Row> joinedDS = inputJoinedWithHierarchies.join(broadcast(substitutionExclusionDS),
    (column("EK").equalTo(lit("C1")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C1"))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C2")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C2")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C3")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C3")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C4")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C4")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C5")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C5"))))),
    "left_outer"
)
.drop(<some_columns>)
```

inner-join

```
Dataset<Row> joinedDS = inputJoinedWithHierarchies.join(broadcast(substitutionExclusionDS),
    (column("EK").equalTo(lit("C1")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C1"))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C2")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C2")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C3")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C3")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C4")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C4")))))
    .or((column("EK").equalTo(lit("C5")).and(column("EV").equalTo(column("C5"))))),
    "left_outer"
)
.drop(<some_columns>)
```

Even after multiple alternate approaches to replace/ enhance `left-outer` join, including broadcast join, everything seems to be super-slow and no reason/ explanation could be established.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Did you check the Spark plan?

Comment: I did. Nothing unusual there.